Synaptic Official Repository List
I use Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS upgraded from 22.04.4 LTS.
I also use Synaptic Package Manager when I want to add or remove some app.
But, I remember the repositories list of Synaptic had 6 or more item. Now I just have 2.
Is it normal?
If I missed some repository, How can I know which is?
Is there some "official repositories list"? Where?

24.04 moved many of the items to /etc/apt/sources.list/ubuntu.list or similar rather than /etc/apt/sources.list. You will find them in the additional sources tab.

Thanks a lot!!!
